# Canbus, Opencan and ISO BUS

Tags: can, canopen

Quick question,

I know about `CanBus` protocol. I'm interesting about `ISOBUS` and `CanOpen`. 
I know that those are exentsion of the `CanBus` protocol. So my question is:

1. Do `ISOBUS` and `CanOpen` need different hardware?
2. Do `ISOBUS` and `CanOpen` can operate on an existing `CanBus` network?
3. Do the changes for those protocol is on the `software` layer or is it on the chip/hardware layer?

Thanks!

Comment: What sites have you googled for this information?

Comment: many, itis not clear if there is need for extra hardware components or not

Comment: "CanBus" is a hardware and data link layer standard, it is not a protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, both are ISO 11898.
2. No. ISOBUS is a derivative of J1939. But I do not own the documents of ISOBUS.
   CANopen is unique above the data link layer, it basically eliminates the option to have multiple protocols on one bus. Most of them don't allow this actually. But ISOBUS and J1939 are compatible because they are designed to be.
3. Since both use CAN bus physical and data link layer, you only need software and maybe a different connector type.

If you are going to work with ISOBUS you should buy the standard!